# Python: How to do nested enumerate for loop?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, nested-loops, enumerate

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`, and for every `file1` line, I’m trying to check against all the lines of `file2`.

So I did a nested enumerate for loop, but checking the first line of `file1` against all the lines of `file2`, the program just completes, rather than moving onto the next `file1` line to check against all the lines of `file2`.

Here is what I have:

```
def testing():
    file1 = open(‘file1.txt’, 'r')
    file2 = open(‘file2.txt’, 'r')

    for index1, line1 in enumerate(file1):
        for index2, line2 in enumerate(file2):
                #              Here it prints the first line of `file1.txt` and after checking against all the lines of `file2.txt` (`for index2, line2 in enumerate(file2.txt)`) it completes, rather then going to the outer loop and proceed looping
                print("THIS IS OUTER FOR LOOP LINE: " + line1 + " WITH LINE NUMBER: " + str(index1))

    file1.close()
    file2.close()
```

How can I check every line of `file1` against all the lines of `file2`? What could I be doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer

Comment: you could use `file2.readlines()` to load the contents of the second file into memory and iterate over that data then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Push the position of **file2** back to the start at the top of each loop.  Either close and reopen it as aryamccarthy suggested, or do it the cleaner way by simply moving the pointer:

```
file1 = open(‘file1.txt’, 'r')
file2 = open(‘file2.txt’, 'r')

for index1, line1 in enumerate(file1):
    file2.seek(0)  # Return to start of file
    for index2, line2 in enumerate(file2):
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reopen `file2` on every iteration. Move that code inside the loop. Otherwise, you reach the end of `file2` after the first outer iteration, and you have nothing left to iterate over in the next round of the outer loop.

Comment: I should note in hindsight that my solution is subject to a race condition. Use Prune's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep every line of each file in separate lists

```
with open(file1) as f:
    content_1 = f.readlines()

with open(file2) as f:
    content_2 = f.readline()
```

and then proceed to compare the lists

```
for index1, line1 in enumerate(content_1):
    for index2, line2 in enumerate(content_2):
        # do your stuff here
```

Comment: With this, you have to store the full contents of each file in memory, which can be risky (or fail) for very large input files.

Comment: agreed, this is not an ideal solution for very big files, but for files of a couple thousand lines it should be ok... when dealing with very big files a better (but slower) idea would be to reopen the second file every time